# Find the integer closest to $(2+\sqrt(2))^6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Evaluating the binomial is a bit hard. I have no idea on how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider $a_n = (2+\sqrt 2)^n + (2-\sqrt 2)^n$. This is a sequence of *integers* that satisfies $a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-2a_{n}$. Note that $0 < 2-\sqrt 2 <1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Add $(2-\sqrt{2})^6$ (a very small number). Can you see something now?